# Finding the relative order of GPX tracks drawn with leaflet-gpx?

Tags: leaflet, layers, z-index

I am displaying many gpx tracks on a map using leaflet-gpx, and I can bring them to the back of the other tracks:

```js
LG = new L.GPX(...)  //loads the track (not detailed here)

LG.on('click',function(e){
var track = e.target;
track.bringToBack();}
```

and this works, the track is behind all the other ones.

However, I would like to be able to bring it back to the front by clicking on it again, with something like this toggle:

```js
if track.isInFront{  //this property does not exist
   track.bringToBack();}
else {track.bringToFront();}
```

but I haven't found the way to get the *track.isInFront* property. I tried getting the `zIndex` via various `track.ZIndex`, or `track.getZIndex()` but it just returns `undefined` or an error: `getZIndex is not a function`.

`track.setZIndex(100)` does not raise an error, and bring the tracks forwards or backwards depending on the value, but I still cannot find a way to read-back the ZIndex.

Is there a way to know where the track is in relation to the others? Or to get its ZIndex ?

As a workaround to bring the track  back to the front, I can clear and redraw the track via the tickboxes of the L.control, but it's a bit more clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GPX tracks are polylines, `zIndex` does not apply to them, since in Leaflet they are implemented as paths within same SVG element. The one that comes later is on the top. Methods `bringToFront()` and `bringToBack` just put selected path at the start/end of SVG element.

This means you have to take care of info if path/layer is in the front. You can do that by using some custom option with any name that does not conflict with Leaflet layer properties, for example `isInFront`.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
LG.on('click', function(e) {
  var track = evt.target;
  var isInFront = track.isInFront;
  if (isInFront)
    track.bringToBack();
  else {
    track.bringToFront();
  }
  track.isInFront = !isInFront;
};
```

The only caveat here is initial setting of `isInFront` option for the GPX path that is the last one added to the map. This one should have `isInFront` option set to 'true', but then the one before that (if there was any) would have it to be set to false. But all this depends on the logic of your app.